# cvc-complex-type.2.4.a: Invalid content was found starting with element 'param'. One of '{param}' is expected

Tags: xml, eclipse, xsd

The following are my xsd and the xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<xs:schema version="1.0" targetNamespace="http://example.com/DashboardSchema" xmlns:tns="http://example.com/DashboardSchema" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">

  <xs:element name="dashboard" type="tns:xmlDashboard"/>

  <xs:complexType name="xmlDashboard">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element name="param" type="tns:xmlDashboardParameter" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>

  <xs:complexType name="xmlDashboardParameter">
    <xs:sequence/>
    <xs:attribute name="module" type="xs:int" use="required"/>
    <xs:attribute name="node" type="xs:int" use="required"/>
    <xs:attribute name="parameter" type="xs:int" use="required"/>
  </xs:complexType>
</xs:schema>


<dashboard xmlns="http://example.com/DashboardSchema"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://example.com/DashboardSchema ./schema3.xsd">
    <param module="1" node="1" parameter="4" />
    <param module="1" node="2" parameter="6" />
    <param module="2" node="0" parameter="4" />
    <param module="2" node="0" parameter="5" />
</dashboard>
```

When I try to validate the xml in Eclipse I get the mentioned error. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably want param to be in the targetNamespace of the schema, in which case you should add `elementFormDefault="qualified"` to the xs:schema element.

This is almost always the correct setting to use. Unfortunately the XSD designers got the default wrong.

It's a poor error message as well: if you were using Saxon, it would say

```
Validation error on line 4 of test.xml:
  XSD: In content of element <dashboard>: The content model does not allow element
  <Q{.../DashboardSchema}param> to appear as the first child. The element is in namespace
  http://example.com/DashboardSchema but it should be in no namespace. 
  Validating /dashboard[1]/param[1]
  See http://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema11-1/#cvc-complex-type clause 2.4
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I'm now getting a different error `Error:(5, 33) src-import.3.1: The namespace attribute, 'http://example.com/PropertyTypeSchema', of an <import> element information item must be identical to the targetNamespace attribute, 'http://example.com/ModulesSchema', of the imported document.`. Do you know what this is? Shall I post the content of the files, maybe in a different question?

Comment: Sounds unrelated, so post a new question.